# Alt key in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have 2 keyboard layouts: english and russian, and use `Alt-Shift` to switch between them.

Windows version of Visual Studio Code works okay with it.

Linux version (under Elementary OS 5 Juno) activates menu bar when i press `Alt-Shift`, so i need to press `Esc` also.

Can this behavious be fixed?

Comment: It's `Alt+Space` on ElementaryOS, not `Alt+Shift`: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/how-can-i-switch-between-keyboard-layouts-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-freya

Comment: I use `Alt-Shift`. It was by default in latest Elementary OS, and i always changed it to `Alt-Shift` in previous versions. The question is not about how to switch keybord layout, but how to disable `Alt` key menu activation in VSCode.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not really. I gone to Mac instead :)